# Google mail IMAP flags

Tags: gmail, imap, rfc

I have noticed IMAP allowes to modify some parts of a message. Specified in [RFC-3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.2)

> A flag can be permanent or session-only on a per-flag basis.

We have 6 speficied flags to set on existing emails:

- \Seen
- \Answered
- \Flagged
- \Deleted
- \Draft
- \Recent

While debugging throu the Java-Mail system using a gmail-account I found further flags like:

- \NonJunk

Quesion:

Where is NonJunk defined? Are there more flags? Is there any official documentation? Shall we request further flags for addition into the specification?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm 100% sure that you mean IMAP and not SMTP.

`\NonJunk` is a user-defined flag, although most clients I've seen tend to use `$Junk` and `$NonJunk` (or sometimes `$NotJunk`), but other clients use `Junk` and `NonJunk` (or sometimes `NotJunk`). And sometimes clients will also use a third flag, `$JunkRecorded` or `JunkRecorded`.

As you can probably guess by now, there is no standard for this. It's just every-client-for-itself.

Comment: `All system flags begin with "\".` from rfc3501.

Comment: So someone is violating the RFC. Podcast at 11.